# How do I find an arbitrary Z coordinate for a corresponding X Y coordinate on a geojson map with geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to locate the Z coordinate of a point on a given map. I am trying to use the `Geodataframe.sjoin()` method. For Testing purposes I am creating an arbitrary point and trying to find the intersection with my geodata. Anytime I am using an actual coordinate from my data for the point ( randomly choosing a geometry's single X Y coordinate) I don't seem to find any intersection whatsoever. The only time I am getting an intersection is when I choose a point where it only intersects with the "outer" polygons ( See picture below).

```
test_point= {'geometry': [ Point(16.844, 46.89) ]  }
gdf_p = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(test_point, crs="EPSG:4326")
gdf_p.crs=data_all.crs #to check if same
```

My data has this format with various geometries
[image: GeoDataFrame with 3D linestring geometries]

This is the original plot of my data based on different Id's:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
data_all.plot(ax=ax1,column='Id')
```

Original plot:

[image: a green curved shape, which perhaps resembles a set of road segments, is at the center of the figure. the shape is clearly made up of a number of different line segments, all with slightly different colors and intensities. there are small green rings at either end of the curved shape, and a shorter straight line intersects the long curved line near the midpoint, forming a shape similar to a stylized lowercase f. the entire set of green lines is set against a much larger blobby orange polygon.]

```
join_inner_df = data_all.sjoin(gdf_p,how='inner')
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
gdf_p.plot(ax=ax1,markersize=300,color='red')
data_all.plot(ax=ax1,column='LaneType')
```

Plot together:

[image: same green curved shape, but with no orange region blob. an intersection point, indicated by a red dot, appears under under the green curved shape near the middle]

The joined GeoDataframe is empty. But if I relocate my point somewhere where the actual track is not covered, but only to covering polygon, I get a multipolygon intersect.

Plot where multipolygon intersect found:

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
gdf_p.plot(ax=ax1, markersize=300, color='red')
data_all.plot(ax=ax1, column='LaneType')
```

[image: same curved shape as last time, but with the intersection point red dot moved to the right center of the figure, and not touching the green curved shape]

I am not sure what I am missing since the geometries inside the track supposed to have intersections just as the polygons outside the track. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely my issue was, that between geometries there are areas which are not described by any geometry, therefore it will have no intersection with my point. A workaround is that I create a buffer around a point, intersect with that, then calculate distance between point and intersected geometries. The closest geometry's closest point's z coordinate can be an approximate result.